# Why have I never seen a "needs restart" message from my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: 16.04, kernel, restart

It's been months now since I set up a brand-new server with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

I have done `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` countless times since then.

Yet I have never seen a "needs restart" message.

Why not? I used to get that message regularly from 12.04 and 14.04.

Comment: What does `cat /proc/sys/kernel/tainted` return?

Comment: @KazWolfe I had to run it with `sudo` because otherwise that file was not found. Running `sudo cat /proc/sys/kernel/tainted` got me `0`.

Comment: Hm. That takes the kernel being live-patched out of the equation. I'll let someone smarter than myself answer.

Comment: Maybe it only comes up after a graphical update.

Comment: @Zacharee1 I used to see it after logging in (terminal only - I have a server) on 12.04 and 14.04.